# Как решить проблемы с производительностью массива RAID5?

Tags: linux, raid

У меня два сервера с аппаратьным массивом RAID 5.
В первом 3 диска, во втором 4 диска.
При копировании больших файлов внутри массива. Скорость по мониторингу забикса одинакова - 100 Мб/сек.
Но утилизациция на первом массиве просто зашкаливает. Второй по утилизации не показывает проблем.

Comment: Что именно вы называете утилизацией и как ее смотрите?

Comment: @avp Забикс имеет в стандартном мониторинге утилизацию и скорость. Утилизация по типу команды iotop

Comment: Вы имеете в виду числа в TOTAL/Actual READ/WRITE ? У меня там никаких процентов, чтобы говорить о "зашкаливает" нет, а вы что видите? Лучше сразу в тексте вопроса приводить все относящиеся к делу реально наблюдаемые цифры

Comment: @avp 100 процентов по iotop и iostat

Comment: Модели массивов и установленные диски одинаковые, отличаются только количеством?